# When is crafting new equipment first possible?

Tags: path-of-exile

After unlocking [the Lush Hideout](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Lush_Hideout) in The Dread Thicket (act 2), I only seem to be able to enhance gear at the crafting bench. When can I craft entirely new equipment?

Answer (score 9):

Crafting in PoE is just using the various currencies, unlocked options in the crafting bench, lab enchants etc. to create a custom made piece of gear.

The earliest you can craft is - right at the start of the game! If you get an orb of Transmutation or Alchemy, apply that to a white base and you will get a magic or rare item back. This is basic currency crafting, and can even be done in Twilight Strand before you enter the Act 1 town.